# Parallels Plesk Panel Update

Tags: plesk

I am trying to do a mirco-update from 10.2 to 10.4 for Parallels Plesk Panel for a Linux server.  The GUI update route is not detecting an available 10.4 version, so I attempted to go the command line interface route, but I cannot locate it anywhere within the the Plesk Panel.  Does anyone know where it is? or is it a separate utility that needs to installed?

Answer (score 0):

/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/autoinstaller

Should get you started

Answer (score 0):

Command line utility you can execute inside the server,

```
For RHEL based OS, /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/autoinstaller --all-versions

For Deb based, /opt/psa/admin/sbin/autoinstaller --all-versions
```